# Angularjs 1.2 Form validation

Tags: javascript, angularjs, validation

I want to know what the best way is to show errors on the input fields that the user is missing when the user has clicked on the deactivated submit btn.

Right now i have this:

```
<form name="userForm" action="/onlinesalg" method="post" ng-submit="submitForm(userForm.$valid)" novalidate>

    <div class="form-group">

        <div class="col-sm-6" ng-class="{ 'has-error' : userForm.fornavn.$invalid && !userForm.fornavn.$pristine }">
            <label class="control-label" for="textinput">Fornavn <span class="star-color">*</span></label>
            <input autocomplete="off" type="text" value="<?php echo set_value('fornavn'); ?>" name="fornavn" ng-model="fornavn" class="form-control" required>
        </div>

        <div class="col-sm-6" ng-class="{ 'has-error' : userForm.efternavn.$invalid && !userForm.efternavn.$pristine }">
            <label class=" control-label" for="textinput">Efternavn <span class="star-color">*</span></label>
            <input autocomplete="off" type="text" value="<?php echo set_value('efternavn'); ?>" name="efternavn" ng-model="efternavn" class="form-control" required>
        </div>
    </div>


    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-sm-12" ng-class="{ 'has-error' : userForm.adresse.$invalid && !userForm.adresse.$pristine }">
            <label class="control-label" for="textinput">Adresse <span class="star-color">*</span></label>
            <input autocomplete="off" type="text" value="<?php echo set_value('adresse'); ?>" name="adresse" ng-model="adresse" class="form-control" required>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


<button ng-disabled="userForm.$invalid || disablezipcodeError" id="membership-box__payBtn" type="submit" name="betaling" class="btn btn-success text-uppercase">Gå til betaling</button>


</form>
```

Comment: Doesn't that make it impossible to click the button?

Comment: No, when all the errors is not invalid its not disabled any more

Answer (score 0, accepted):

rather than deactivating the submit button, you can allow user to submit. and if there are any errors, show those errors, and suspend the submit process

why is that better, if button is disabled, and no error message are displayed, user wont be able to know the reason why the button is disabled.

and if you try showing errors even before user presses the submit button, you ui would look too clutered..

btw, thats just my opinion, and yes you should not ask opinion based questions on SO, read the guidelines.

Comment: Thanks that what i im going with